# Which key values in Dictionary were not updated?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary whose keys are integers and values are lists, for each key list is updated in every iteration. Also new keys are added. But there may be situations where some key values are not updated.

whats the most efficient way to know which keys were not updated?

I can iterate all lists in dictionary and check from length if that list was updated or not but is there a better way?

Note: Integer Keys are not consecutive numbers. Therefore using simple lists or arrays does not seem like an option

Comment: You can create a set of the keys included and/or the keys excluded. Please include some sample code.

Comment: good idea. I can get a set of keys from dictionary and remove the key which is updated. at end i will have a set of keys which were not updated. Thanks.
And sorry I normally write pseudo code on my notebook before actually starting code. feels more comfortable as I normally try to contemplate problems which can occur with my approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the solution @Scott Skiles made in a comment, I would add a value to the dictionary, next to the list, that designates the most recent iteration when the key was modified:

```
my_dict = {}
iteration_num = 0
while True:
    updates_to_make = some_function_producing_2tuples()
    # iterate through new additions, and add them to the list
    for key, value in updates_to_make:
        # the 'value' in my_dict is a 2-tuple (last_updated, list)
        # we replace last_updated every time we change the key somehow
        if key in my_dict:
            my_dict[key][1].append(value)
            my_dict[key][0] = iteration_num
        else:
            my_dict[key] = (iteration_num, [value])
    ...
    iteration_num += 1
```

You can then figure out which keys are or are not updated by applying a filter:

```
updated_keys = [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if v[0] == iteration_num]
```